# pass data from vb to aspx with googlemaps api

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i need to show some marker on googlemaps.
I have write this section and i pass the data with locationList array, but the map don't show all my markers. Can you help me for understand where i have the problem?
Thank's for answers.

```
<asp:Content id="CustomScripts" ContentPlaceHolderID="CustomScript"  runat ="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.837367, 11.029718),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        var temp = locationList
        for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
            var args = locationList[i].split(",");
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(args[0], args[1])
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map
            });
            var j = i + 1;
            marker.setTitle(message[i].replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""));
            attachSecretMessage(marker, i);
        }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function attachSecretMessage(marker, number) {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
            content: message[number],
            size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MainContent_time1 , #MainContent_time2").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
            pick12HourFormat: false
        });

        $("#MainContent_time1 , #MainContent_time2").keydown(function (e) {
            var charCode = e.which;
            if (charCode != 8 && charCode != 46) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#" + id).val("");
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```